# Tor SOCKS5 Not Working With Anything Other Than Tor Browser

Tags: tails, torsocks, socks

I am running Tails OS on a live USB and am attempting to run traffic through Tor.

The Tor Browser is working via the SOCKS5 proxy on 127.0.0.1:9050.

When I try to run:

```
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://check.torproject.org
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9050: Connection refused
```

The Tor service is running on ports 9050 and 9150, but I cannot connect to either of them via anything other than the browser.

Trying:

```
torify -P 9050 curl https://check.torproject.org
```

Returns:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: check.torproject.org
```

And:

```
torify -P 9150 curl https://check.torproject.org
```

The same:

```
1634724584 PERROR torsocks[23634]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: check.torproject.org
```

/etc/tor/torrc:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1, and Tor will ignore it

AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
AutomapHostsSuffixes .exit,.onion
AvoidDiskWrites 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,meek_lite exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy managed
ControlPort 127.0.0.1:9052
DNSPort 5353
Log notice file /var/log/tor/log
RunAsDaemon 0
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9150 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort 
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9062 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
SocksPort 10.200.1.1:9050 IsolateSOCKSAuth KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
TransPort 127.0.0.1:9040
WarnPlaintextPorts 23,109
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use this recently, but you could try

- `curl https://check.torproject.org`, at some point `curl` was automatically torified
- `torify curl https://check.torproject.org` if the first option does not work

Comment: Running ```torify curl https://check.torproject.org``` gives the output ```1634722466 PERROR torsocks[21583]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: check.torproject.org```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Tails bad architecture playing tricks on you: Tor is fine working with any SOCKS5 or HTTP client via the corresponding port. As far as I remember - it was a firewall rules for that in Tails, check your firewall tables. And if you need a proper OS-wide security *without* problems *and* with a greater security and convenience - check out a QubesOS

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your `/etc/hosts` for entry starting with `::1` for localhost?

If you have it, please try:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org
```

You can also try adding SOCKS port listening on `::1` address to your torrc:

```
SocksPort [::1]:9050 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
```